# layover via Singapore (8hrs) and Taipei(17hrs). Do I need transit visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, sin, tpe

I have booked "Delhi - Singapore(8hr layover) - Taipei (Taoyuan)(17hr layover) - LA". I am an Indian holding a valid F1 visa. is transit visa needed ? [image]

Comment: This look like a stitched itinerary, especially that 6E-CI change

Answer (score 4):

TIMATIC states, for Singapore :

> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

I am not certain, but you are unlikely to fulfil the international transit area requirement for your change between Indigo and China Airlines, especially with checked luggage

But, you can leave it, and visit the country for those 8h, with the VFTF

> Nationals of India with a confirmed onward air or cruise ticket to a third country within 96 hours under the Visa Free Transit Facility (VFTF). They must:
>
> - have an entry visa issued by Australia, Canada, Germany, Japan, New Zealand, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom valid for a minimum of one
>   month, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

---

For Taiwan, you are more likely to remain in the international transit area even though 17h in the transit area is a very long time, and you may want to secure a Taiwanese visa to allow you to visit

> #### Visa exemption treatment for Indian passport holders
>
> With a valid visa or an expired visa less than 10 years prior to the
> date of arrival in Taiwan or permanent resident certificate issued by
> Australia, Canada, Japan, Korea, New Zealand, any of the Schengen
> countries, the United Kingdom, the United States, or possesses an
> entry visa or resident card issued by the ROC at any point in the past
> 10 years, are eligible to apply online for an ROC Travel Authorization
> Certificate. (https://www.roc-taiwan.org/in_en/post/1026.html)

You apply on the [Taiwanese Immigration](https://niaspeedy.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast) website and it's entirely free of charge

Comment: Singapore T1 to T3 can be transited airside.  If (and only if) they have purchased the ticket as a single booking, their luggage will also be transferred.

Comment: @lambshaanxy You never know with Indigo, but I doubt this is a single ticket

Comment: @lambshaanxy Indeed, this is not a flight sold by either airline, this is not a single ticket

Comment: If things haven't changed - T1-T3 have a light rail connection. T4 has a bus airside from.. I THINK T3, but its been a while since I worked there.